# Can't create foreign key to ApplicationUser in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Package manager is throwing errors when trying different things. I want to create a foreign key to 'ApplicationUser' entity in my 'YogaSpace' entity. I've looked at multiple different threads online to see how to accomplish this and I think my code first code is correct. Here is what I've done and here is the error I'm getting in package manager when updating the database.

```
public class YogaSpace
{
    public int YogaSpaceId { get; set; }
    //other members left out to save space
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string ApplicationUserRefId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserRefId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //other members left out to save space
    public virtual ICollection<YogaSpace> YogaSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the error message I receive in package manager console when updating the database.

> EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.YogaSpaces.User_Id', @newname = N'ApplicationUserRefId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.

There is no 'YogaSpaces.User_Id' I'm creating, it seems like Entity Framework is creating it for me. ?? Why?? So I thought maybe I needed to put ApplicationUser in my context class seen below.

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

I tried this and ran update database and received this different error message.

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'YogaBandy.DomainClasses.Models.ApplicationUser'.

I'm not sure what I need to do here but this is a headache!

Comment: EF is trying to apply a migration that renames User_Id to ApplicationUserRefId. You did a bad manipulation that screw up with the db model EF kept for the next Migration.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the initial migration or a migration on an existing schema? If the latter there may already be a `User_Id` column on the table from a previous build and because you're now adding an explicit column (`ApplicationUserRefId`) it now needs to rename the existing column.

It would help if you posted the migration.

Comment: This isn't the initial migration, I don't think. I've already done a enable-migrations -initialMigration call and created the database. But looking at the table I don't see User_Id. I can delete the db and start over, this is just a test project??

Comment: Without posting the migration file, because it's long. I looked through it and don't see any User_Id column anywhere.

Comment: If all you're doing is adding the `ApplicationUser` as a foreign key / navigation property and this isn't the initial migration then the migration shouldn't be that long. It sounds like you've maybe buggered things up somewhere so I agree that deleting the db and starting over would be your best bet.